# doesn't css animation not work on ios chrome?

Tags: ios, reactjs, web, tailwind-css, emotion

i'm making an animation that show the menu by squentially giving delays. below is my code (twin.macro + emotion).

```
const Menu = ({ onClose }: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-screen z-menu">
        <StaticImage className="w-full h-screen" src="../../static/images/bg-main.png" alt="배경" />
      </div>
      <div className="absolute top-0 left-0  w-full h-screen bg-menu z-menu">
        <button className="absolute top-4 right-4 text-white hover:text-gray-200" onClick={onClose}>
          <CloseIcon />
        </button>
        <Responsive className="py-20">
          /* menu */
          <ul className="flex flex-col items-start gap-9 overflow-hidden">
            <Item>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Link to="/project">Project</Link>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Link to="/story">Story</Link>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Link to="/group">Group</Link>
            </Item>
          </ul>
        </Responsive>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Menu;

const showMenu = keyframes`
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  } 
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
`;

const Item = styled.li`
  ${tw`-translate-x-full text-4xl font-bold text-white transition will-change-transform hover:text-gray-200`};
  &:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation: ${showMenu} 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
    -webkit-animation: ${showMenu} 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
  }
  &:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation: ${showMenu} 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: ${showMenu} 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s forwards;
  }
  &:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation: ${showMenu} 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: ${showMenu} 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s forwards;
  }
  &:nth-of-type(4) {
    animation: ${showMenu} 0.3s ease-in-out 0.3s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: ${showMenu} 0.3s ease-in-out 0.3s forwards;
  }
`;
```

it works well in desktop browsers and ios safari, but animation breaks off in ios chrome. is it a bug? any way solution?

i want it to work properly on ios chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from `will-change`.

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) doc, it is intended to be used as a last resort. So maybe Google took it off to avoid performance problems.

Consider using `transform` property instead.

Hope it helps

Comment: thx for comment. i've already tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: and when i looked it up, there's this problem of webkit.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1231712